# Chunking for Tamil language

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, chunking, indic

I want to use the NLTK chunker for Tamil language (which is an Indic language). [However, it says that it doesn't support Unicode because it uses the 'pre' module for regular expressions.](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chunk.html)

> ### Unresolved Issues
>
> If we use the `re` module for regular expressions, Python's regular
>   expression engine generates "maximum recursion depth exceeded" errors
>   when processing very large texts, even for regular expressions that
>   should not require any recursion.  We therefore use the `pre` module
>   instead.  But note that `pre` does not include Unicode support, so
>   this module will not work with unicode strings.

Any suggestion for a work around or another way to accomplish it?

Comment: Tamil Shallow Parser: http://ltrc.iiit.ac.in/showfile.php?filename=downloads/shallow_parser.php

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is not only clearly stated, but sourced with a reference documenting the problem. It could be improved by making it more general: Any language requiring Unicode would benefit from an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chunkers are language-specific, so you need to train one for Tamil anyway. Of course if you are happy with available off-the-shelf solutions (I've got no idea if there are any, e.g. if the link in the now-deleted answer is any good), you can stop reading here. If not, you can train your own but you'll need a corpus that is annotated with the chunks you want to recognize: perhaps you are after NP chunks (the usual case), but maybe it's something else.

Once you have an annotated corpus, look carefully at chapters 6 and 7 of the NLTK book, and especially [section 7.3, Developing and evaluating chunkers.](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#developing-and-evaluating-chunkers). While Chapter 7 begins with the nltk's regexp chunker, keep reading and you'll see how to build a "sequence classifier" that does not rely on the nltk's regexp-based chunking engine. ([Chapter 6](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) is essential for this, so don't skip it).

It's not a trivial task: You need to understand the classifier approach, put the pieces together, probably convert your corpus to [IOB format](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#reading-iob-format-and-the-conll-2000-corpus), and finally select features that will give you satisfactory performance. But it is pretty straightforward, and can be carried out for any language or chunking task for which you have an annotated corpus. The only open-ended part is thinking up contextual cues that you can convert into features to help the classifier decide correctly, and experimenting until you find a good mix. (On the up side, it is a much more powerful approach than pure regexp-based solutions, even for ascii text).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LTRC](http://ltrc.iiit.ac.in/)'s [Shallow Parser](http://ltrc.iiit.ac.in/showfile.php?filename=downloads/shallow_parser.php) for Tamil Language.

You can check online demo, [here](http://ltrc.iiit.ac.in/analyzer/tamil/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13157075)

Comment: Answer is giving reference to alternative library/software and thats essential parts of the answer. I had also put Website's homepage link so in case if specific links become invalid, user can still visit main website and find solution.

Comment: @Ashok Ramachandran - Were you able to chunk tamil language sentences?